# Input field not resetting value - AngularJS 2

Tags: typescript, angular

```
export class ParametersForm {
  myForm: ControlGroup;
  systemParameters: AbstractControl;
  arr: number[];
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group({
      "realisations" : [""],
      "numConstSteps" : [""],
      "timeHorizon": [""],
      "continuationStep" : [""],
      "continuationStepSign" : [""],
      "numberOfModelParameters" : [""],
      "systemParameters" : [],
      "param" : [""],
      "netLogoFile" : [""],
      "numberOfModelVariables" : [""],
      "restrictOperator" : [""],
      "liftOperator" : [""],
      "xInitial" : [""]

    });
    this.arr = [];
    this.systemParameters = this.myForm.controls["systemParameters"];
  }
  addToArray(value: any): void {
    this.arr.push(value);
    this.systemParameters = null;
  }
  onSubmit(form: any): void {
    console.log(this.arr);
    form.systemParameters = this.arr;
    console.log("your submitted value:", form)
  }
}
```

form

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parameters-form',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
      <h1>Parameters Form</h1>

      <form [ngFormModel]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)" class="ui form">

<div class="field">
            <label for="systemParameters">System Parameterss</label>
            <input type="number"
                   id="systemParameters"
                   placeholder="systemParameters Param"
                   [ngFormControl]="myForm.controls['systemParameters']" #systemParam>

            <button type="button" (click)="addToArray(systemParam.value)">Add</button>
          </div>

<button type="submit" class="ui button">Submit</button>
      </form>
    `
})
```

The problem is when i click the "add" button the field is not resetting so that i can input my next value without removing old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
this.systemParameters = null;
```

this should work

```
import { Control } from "angular2/common";

(<Control>this.systemParameters).updateValue('');
```

Comment: Um thanks but this does not compile "cannot find name control"

Comment: You need to import `Control` I guess.